# Malfunction of the onPressed Flutter property

Tags: flutter, button, dart, mobile

- I created an extended class from a RaisedButton. When passing the onPressed parameter, the class rejects saying that the drive is null.
- The Class

```
class VecRaisedButton extends RaisedButton {
  VecRaisedButton({
    text,
    elevation,
    onPressed,
    colorButton = CorPrimaria,
    colorFont,
    splashColor: CorBranca
  }) :
    super(
      child:VecText(text: text, textAlign: TextAlign.center, color: colorFont),
      shape:RoundedRectangleBorder( borderRadius: BordaArredondadaApenas4(10, 10, 10, 10)),
      splashColor:splashColor,
      elevation:elevation,
      onPressed: () => onPressed,
      color:colorButton,
    );
}
```

- Class call

```
child: VecRaisedButton(
   text: "Enviar",
   colorFont: CorBranca,
   onPressed: Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Layout_Menu())),
)
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
  elevation:elevation,
  onPressed: () => onPressed,
```

to:

```
  elevation: elevation,
  onPressed: onPressed, // just pass along the Function
```

and, this:

```
   colorFont: CorBranca,
   onPressed: Navigator.push(context,
```

to this:

```
   colorFont: CorBranca,
   onPressed: () => Navigator.push(context, // onPressed takes a Function
```

However, in general you should *compose* new widgets rather than extending. That means making a class that extends `StatelessWidget` and then returning a correctly styled raised button in your new widget's `build`.

Comment: Minimal example https://dartpad.dev/b6409e10de32b280b8938aa75364fa7b. Similar concept to this answer